# flutter http request/response details including headers?

Tags: flutter, dart

while `http` request details can easily be inspected in browser dev tools(for web app), I tried to explore, where I can find the same for requests sent in flutter App, but couldn't locate it.

like for example - I can see the actual response from api by `print(response)`, but I am talking about complete request response including `headers`.

I am using VScode IDE for Flutter.

**update:**

I want to view the headers sent like `response.header`. reason for the same is like I am using `flutter cahe manager` and the issue I am facing is like I have set the -`cache control max-age=1`.

so the flutter should try to fetch the same every time I access the page, which it is doing, but it is serving the page from the cache and then fetching the request. so if there is any change is on server side, it doesn't reflect when first open the page, but shows the change on every second visit.

so what I want is like if the flutter gets `304 response` from server, it will serve from the cache else it should serve from the fetched data. but it is not happening.

also the `response.header` is not showing response code like it is `200` or `304`, so that flutter can fetch or serve from cache.

**Actual code being used is like this:**

```
Future<MyUserProfile> fetchMyUserProfile() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final userid = prefs.getString('user_id');
  var userProfile =  await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile("url");        
  final response = await userProfile.readAsString();



 if (response != '') {
    print(userProfile);
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return MyUserProfile.fromJson(json.decode(response));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Profile');
  }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Don't wanna be rude, but the information you are looking for is quite easy to find... That is if you look in the right place, like official documentation.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpResponse-class.html

> HttpResponse class ... headers → HttpHeaders Returns the response
> headers. [...] read-only

```
http.Response response = await http.get(url...
print(response.headers);
```

**EDIT:** Answering the sub-question that was added to the original question.

To check what the status code is you simply access it via `response.statusCode`

Example:

```
  http.Response response = await http.get(url...
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // do something
  } else if (response.statusCode == 304) {
    // do something else
  } else {
    // handle this
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. and How I can get the request header? can you please help me with that as well.

Comment: You mean how to attach headers to your request? [Cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data) , example: `http.Response response = await http.post(yourUrl,headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',},body: jsonEncode({'something': someValue,})).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but I am not able to use `response.statusCode` see my update. any idea how can get around this?

Comment: Is it possible to get `content-disposition: ` from http response?